# How to keep repeated zeros when filling in data in R?

Tags: r

Hello everyone and many thanks in advance for your help,

[Kit of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0RxY.png)

As can be seen above, I have to assign numerical values from column A (ordered real numbers) to column B (unordered real numbers), so that the number 4193 in column B matches the number 1 in column A each and every time, the number 15 in column B matches the number 2 in column A each and every time, and so on and so forth (this is just a random sample that I've presented as an example, as I'm working with an extremely large dataset). This should have been no big deal, but the thing is that these two columns are of different size (column A is much larger than column B).

In total, there are 1.048.575 values in Column A and 10.571 values in Column B.

The code that I've been using is, as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(rep(list(1048575))
), B = c(rep(list(10571)))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(-10571L, -1048575L))

Result <- rep(B, table(A)[seq_along(B)])

print(Result)
```

The expected output should look something like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBKfR.png)

However, the problem is that there are many 0s (zeros) in Column B that are missing in the final output when I run the code for the complete dataset, and I am not sure how to solve this problem. To be more precise, I get 959.031 instead of 1.048.575 values because of this (obviously, I need to get 1.048.575 values, zeros including).

Finally (and I am sorry for asking this, but I am relatively new to R), once there is a perfect match between two variables, how can I "move" the results to the original .xlsx (or .csv) file from which the data was taken, so that the results obtained by working in R are reflected there?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image showed, perhaps, we need - i.e. here we assume the number of non-NA `unique` values in 'B' will be the same as the number of unique values in 'A', thus `rep`licate those values and create the data.frame

```
un1 <- na.omit(unique(df1$B))
out <- data.frame(A, B = rep(un1, table(df1$A)))
```

This can be written as `csv` with `write.csv`

```
write.csv(out, 'file.csv', row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Or with `writexl`

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(out, 'file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! It worked just fine. Thank you so very much! The only thing is... do you know now how to export this result to the original .xlsx (or, alternatively, a .csv file)? Thanks once again!

Comment: @ArtUr693 try the update

Comment: Actually, I'm so sorry, but I've just realised that the number 4193 is repeated all the time in Column B (from the number 1 up to the number 1048575 in Column A). Would you know, by chance, how this could be fixed in your code? Many thanks and my apologies for missing out on this!

Comment: @ArtUr693 if you look at the `rep` it is replicating each unique value of 'un1' by the order of count from 'A' column